# Login Modul Error - Yii

Tags: yii

I am trying to create a login module in Yi , But I am having thsi error and I really donot understand what is is all as I am totally a beginner in Yii. Please tell me what the problem it is and olution for this problem .

**Property "UserIdentity.Email" is not defined.**

```
C:\wamp\www\topicoll\protected\components\UserIdentity.php(21)

09 {
10     /**
11      * Authenticates a user.
12      * The example implementation makes sure if the username and password
13      * are both 'demo'.
14      * In practical applications, this should be changed to authenticate
15      * against some persistent user identity storage (e.g. database).
16      * @return boolean whether authentication succeeds.
17      */
18     public function authenticate()
19     {
20             
21                 $users = TblUser::model()->find('Email=?',array($this->Email));
22     //    $user= TblUser::User::model()->find('LOWER(Email)=?',array(strtolower($this->Email)));
23         if($users===null)
24             $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
25         else if(!$users->validatePassword($this->password))
26             $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
27         else
28         {
29             $this->_id=$users->id;
30             $this->Email=$users->Email;
31             $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
32         }
33         return $this->errorCode==self::ERROR_NONE;
Stack Trace
#0  
–  C:\wamp\www\topicoll\protected\components\UserIdentity.php(21): CComponent->__get("Email")
16      * @return boolean whether authentication succeeds.
17      */
18     public function authenticate()
19     {
20             
21                 $users = TblUser::model()->find('Email=?',array($this->Email));
22     //    $user= TblUser::User::model()->find('LOWER(Email)=?',array(strtolower($this->Email)));
23         if($users===null)
24             $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
25         else if(!$users->validatePassword($this->password))
26             $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
#1  
–  C:\wamp\www\topicoll\protected\models\LoginForm.php(45): UserIdentity->authenticate()
40      * This is the 'authenticate' validator as declared in rules().
41      */
42     public function authenticate($attribute, $params) {
43         if (!$this->hasErrors()) {
44             $this->_identity = new UserIdentity($this->Email, $this->password);
45             if (!$this->_identity->authenticate())
46                 $this->addError('password', 'Incorrect username or password.');
47         }
48     }
49 
50     /**
#2  
+  C:\wamp\www\yii\framework\validators\CInlineValidator.php(43): LoginForm->authenticate("password", array())
#3  
+  C:\wamp\www\yii\framework\validators\CValidator.php(197): CInlineValidator->validateAttribute(LoginForm, "password")
#4  
+  C:\wamp\www\yii\framework\base\CModel.php(158): CValidator->validate(LoginForm, null)
#5  
–  C:\wamp\www\topicoll\protected\controllers\SiteController.php(110): CModel->validate()
105         {
106             $model->attributes=$_POST['LoginForm'];
107                         
108 //                        var_dump($model);
109             // validate user input and redirect to the previous page if valid
110             if($model->validate() && $model->login())
111                         {
112                             $this->redirect(array('site/login', 'email'=>$model->Email));
113                             
114                             echo $model->Email;
115                            
#6  
+  C:\wamp\www\yii\framework\web\actions\CInlineAction.php(50): SiteController->actionLogin()
#7  
+  C:\wamp\www\yii\framework\web\CController.php(309): CInlineAction->runWithParams(array("r" => "site/login"))
#8  
+  C:\wamp\www\yii\framework\web\CController.php(287): CController->runAction(CInlineAction)
#9  
+  C:\wamp\www\yii\framework\web\CController.php(266): CController->runActionWithFilters(CInlineAction, array())
#10 
+  C:\wamp\www\yii\framework\web\CWebApplication.php(276): CController->run("login")
#11 
+  C:\wamp\www\yii\framework\web\CWebApplication.php(135): CWebApplication->runController("site/login")
#12 
+  C:\wamp\www\yii\framework\base\CApplication.php(162): CWebApplication->processRequest()
#13 
+  C:\wamp\www\topicoll\index.php(13): CApplication->run()
2012-09-28 07:22:44 Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) PHP/5.3.8 Yii Framework/1.1.10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace **$this->Email**  with **$this->username**  in your UserIdentity.php

Comment: Why did this work? I changed it so that a user uses his/her email to log in...why do we not need to change the user identity username field? is it @param2